# Emacs Auto indent mode

Tags: emacs

I have the following script working 
[Emacs Auto Indent Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/auto-indent-mode.el)

it does auto indenting but it has one problem when i start marking regions and go down by lines each time i hit the indention the marking is canceled and it kind-of annoyance me.

How can this be fixed or are there any alternatives? or how can i disable auto indention when marking region is active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have [Transient Mark mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/TransientMarkMode) enabled.  Try putting this at the bottom or your `~/.emacs` file:

```
;; Turn off Transient Mark mode.
(transient-mark-mode -1)
```

and restart Emacs.